# Notification from the settings app on iOS?

Tags: ios, notifications

I just got a notification from the settings app on my iPhone.
I have notification previews turned off, so I can't see what the notification was about until I tap it on the lock screen.

When I do that it simply asked for my passcode then takes me into face ID section of settings.

So I don't seem to have any way of finding out what that notification was actually about.
It also seems a bit suspicious because it asked me to enter my passcode. (I notice now that is ordinary behaviour when you enter the Face ID and passcode section within settings).

I thought this might have been triggered by my receiving a text message but actually I don't think it was.

One thing I think I did almost exactly the time that notification was received is add an ICS file to calendar on my Mac.

Wondered if anyone can shed any light.

Answer (score 1):

Notifications in settings are usually about :

- iCloud parameters not finalised or paiement method expired (iCloud)
- New version of iOS available (Général / software update)
- short storage (general/ storage)

Comment: I found the answer - by realising that I could change notification previews to on, so see what the notification was about. It was telling me I could use Apple Watch to unlock iPhone. Had recently switched on my Apple Watch. Nice to solve this.. Sometimes I'm too obsessed with detail though.. !

Comment: Be obsessed can make you learn.